# Where are the auth logs in OpenShift?

Tags: authentication, logging, openshift, audit-logging

I'm trying to audit access logs (including failed access attempts). I have a fluentd collector running so I can export the logs but I can't find them to export them! I thought [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/logging/cluster-logging-viewing.html) might help, but when I use the console and go to
Workloads → Pods → fluentd or cluster logging logs
I don't see auth events anywhere there.

Comment: The link you posted is about general workload logs. Have you also checked [the audit log](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/nodes/nodes/nodes-nodes-audit-log.html)?

Comment: ^ Thank you, I checked the audit logs. I pulled 500,000 lines of those for each of my cluster nodes and I'm searching them now. I see some oauth events, but I don't see user login details.